# Checking number range not working

Tags: c#

```
private bool DataValidation(string Checker)
{
    int i;
    if (Int32.TryParse(Checker, out i))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

private void NumberChecker()
{
    if (int.Parse(txtRank.Text) >= 0 || int.Parse(txtRank.Text) <= 50)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, string.Empty);
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "Between 1 and 50 please!");
    }
}

private void txtRank_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataValidation(txtRank.Text) == false)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "Must be numeric!");
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, string.Empty);
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }

    NumberChecker();
}
```

I've been trying to get this to work for about 4 hours, can someone please tell me why it keeps saying "String in the wrong format" I've tried all of this inside the the validation event, nothing I do is working. I am not understanding why.

**Update:**

```
private void txtRank_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (DataValidation(txtRank.Text) == false)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "Must be numeric!");
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, string.Empty);
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }

    if (Convert.ToInt32(txtRank.Text) >= 0 && Convert.ToInt32(txtRank.Text) <= 50)
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, string.Empty);
        errorProvider1.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "Between 1 and 50 please!");
    }
}
```

if i use the code above, i can either do one or the other, but i have to comment out a section of code in order to do that.

Comment: It should be above 0 ***OR*** below 50? Or did you mean to say `&&` ;)

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: yes i have tried &&, it didn't work. if (int.Parse(txtRank.Text) >= 0 || int.Parse(txtRank.Text) <= 50) is giving me the error, yet, if i just run the datavalidation, that works, i can either have one working or the other at the same time, not both

Comment: That means the value in `txtRank.Text` is not a valid integer. Use `int.TryParse` first to make sure the strings are valid integers.

Comment: @Thebluefish is talking about a different issue than your error, Jon. `value >= 0 || value <= 50` (greater than 0 *OR* less than 50) will be true for any value, since 51 is greater than 0 and -1 is less than 50. You *do* want an `&&` in that location, but it's not the answer to your primary problem.

Comment: Side note: Combining `.TryParse()` and `.Parse()` is a bad practice. Use `.TryParse()` which is enough to validate and get the value at the same time.

Comment: You can just replace your `if` statement with: `int num; if (int.TryParse(textRank.Text, out num) && num > 0 && num <= 50)`

Comment: Okay i will try, i have updated the code so you guys can see what i initially did

Comment: Put a try{}catch{} statements in your code, and step through using the debugger.

Comment: Time to go home, sleep it off.  Tomorrow you'll instantly see the bug.

Comment: Also, note that your `DataValidation` method isn't as useful as just calling `int.TryParse` in your main code, since you need the value as an integer for the next comparisons (you end up calling `int.TryParse` in `DataValidation` and then call `int.Parse` on the same string again to see if the number is within range).

Comment: Thanks guys, i was able to figure this out with your help, can't thank you enough!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing a *lot* of stuff here that isn't necessary at all.

First off: Assuming that the if statement in your `DataValidation` method is only intended to have the `return true` and `return false`, the if statement is totally unnecessary. You could just say `return Int32.TryParse(Checker, out i);` and it would do the exact same thing. In fact, you could remove the `int i` in the first place, and just do this:

```
private bool DataValidation(string Checker) {
    return Int32.TryParse(Checker, out int i);
}
```

`out int i` creates a temporary variable... and since the `DataValidation` method is now a single method call, you may realize that the whole method is now unnecessary. You could simply replace any call to `DataValidation(someString)` with `Int32.TryParse(someString, out int i)` with no side effects.

---

Moving on to your `NumberChecker` method, the error becomes immediately apparent:

```
if (int.Parse(txtRank.Text) >= 0 || int.Parse(txtRank.Text) <= 50)
```

This is the only place in your code where you are parsing a string without checking to ensure that it's a number first. Evidently, `txtRank.Text` is a string that is not a proper number. This is actually where `TryParse` would come in handy.

I'm going to assume that you don't know exactly what `TryParse` does and that you were only using it as an error checker, which is okay, because the function of `out` arguments aren't immediately apparent.

The `out` keyword, effectively, allows a function to change the thing that was passed in. Take the following code snippet:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    String foo = "abc";
    DoSomething(out foo);
    Console.WriteLine(foo);
}

private static void DoSomething(out String something)
{
    something = "def";
}
```

Despite `DoSomething` not returning a value, the `Console.WriteLine(foo);` will write `def` rather than `abc`. `Int32.TryParse` uses this to its advantage: It *returns* a `bool` that says whether the operation was successful or not. And if it *was* successful, it stores the result in the variable used as the `out` argument.

As such, your `NumberChecker` method should look something like this:

```
private void NumberChecker()
{
    int num = null;
    if (Int32.TryParse(txtRank.Text, out num) {
        // if TryParse returns true, then we have a result in `num`.
        if (num >= 0 && num <= 50)
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, string.Empty);
            errorProvider1.Clear();
        }
        else // txtRank.Text is a number, but is not within the range
        {
            errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "Between 1 and 50 please!");
        }
    }
    else // txtRank.Text is not a number to begin with
    {
        errorProvider1.SetError(txtRank, "txtRank.Text is not a number!");
    }
}
```

Worth noting: Since `NumberChecker()` can now handle the case of invalid text like `txtRank_Validating()` used to, you can now remove `txtRank_Validating()` as well. `NumberChecker()` is now the only necessary code.

---

One final thing worth noting: In your original code, although your `txtRank_Validating()` has if statements for in case `txtRank.Text` was not a number, the reason it was still failing was because `NumberChecker()` was called at the end of the method *whether the text was a number or not.* In that sense, the *easiest* solution would have just been to move the `NumberChecker();` call to after `errorProvider1.Clear();` inside the `else` block. But I think the rest of the details in this answer are worth taking note of.

Comment: People down voting to a legitimate question after someone has spent hours on end to work out, wow, unbelievable.